# ExtJs - border layout - splitter config

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

1. My panel with `border` layout looks like this:

   ```
   var oSplitPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    lid   : 'splitpanel',
    layout: 'border',
    border: 0,
    style: { border: 0 }
    height: 150,
    items: [{
      split: true,
      flex: 1,
      region: 'west',
      xtype: 'panel',
      lid: 'panelwest',
      layout: 'fit',
      minWidth: 200
    }]
   });
   ```
2. Then another panel gets added to this `west` region panel:

   ```
   oSplitPanel.query('[lid=panelwest]')[0].add(oExplorerPanel);
   ```
3. Then this split panel gets added to my main view:

   ```
   that.getView().add(oSplitPanel);
   ```
4. Then in another function, I add the `center` panel:

   ```
   var oAddPanelRight = {
          split: true,
          flex: 3,
          region: 'center',
          xtype: 'panel',
          lid: 'panelcenter',
          layout: 'fit',
          border: 0
       };

   oSplitPanel.add(oAddPanelRight);
   ```

**Problem:**

Everything works perfect this way, however **I want to change (limit) the splitter's own width** (this splitter is in between `west` and `center` panels to resize their width).

**What I tried:**

1. Try to change the width of splitters:

   ```
    listeners: {
       afterrender: function() {
          // error following, 'splitters' does not exist
          oSplitPanel.layout.splitters.west.setWidth(1);
          oSplitPanel.doLayout();
       }
    }
   ```
2. Adding a negative margin to the `center` panel:

   ```
            // Tried this:
            margin: '0 0 0 -4'

            // And that:
            style: {
               border: 0,
               marginLeft: '-3px'
            }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *oSplitPanel* object/instance does not have the *split* param set to true and has therefor no splitter applied. The splitter get applied to *oAddPanelRight* object/instance and the nested panel of the *oSplitPanel*, maybe also to the panel you add later. Can't tell that.

So you just looked at the wrong class.

Btw. to get a splitter for the class itself you don't need look at `oSplitPanel.layout.splitters` Just look at the `splitter` prop of the class.

Comment: Thanks. It now works by adding the listener to my initial panel `west`: using `listeners: {
                  afterrender: function() {
                     this.splitter.width = 1;
                     oSplitPanel.doLayout();
                  }
               }`

Comment: @Indianer You're welcome! :) I alkso added a little subnote concerning  splitter refs

Answer (score 2):

Or use event "add"

```
listeners: {
    add: function (me, item) {
        if (item.xtype == 'bordersplitter') item.width = 2;
    }
},
```

Demo here http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-border-layout-splitter-width